# Двоеточие или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Как будет правильнее:
"Мое мнение – видеорегистратор достоин 9 баллов из 10."
или
"Мое мнение: видеорегистратор достоин 9 баллов из 10."?

Answer (score 4):

To simplify there's sort of rule of thumb you can keep in mind. Go for dash when you can imagine that is acceptable for this particular phrase to use "is" instead. 
Go for colon when you can imagine that phrase could be rephrased by adding something like "Here's what...".

In this particular case both of rules are acceptable:

- Моё мнение [является/есть] -
- [Вот] моё мнение: ...

===========

Если вместо тире можно представить глагол-связку (например "есть", "является") то тире подходит. Если к фразе можно добавить что-то вроде "вот что", "вот какие" - то уместно двоеточие.

Примеры @user907860 хорошие, но в отличие от фразы "я знал:" заканчивающейся глаголом - ([вот что] я знал) грань тут тонкая, и в данном конкретном случае уместны оба знака препинания.

Answer (score 2):

Двоеточие.

> 2. Второе простое предложение дополняет содержание первого (дополнительные отношения). Перед вторым предложением можно вставить союз что.
>
> Ср.: Я знал: удар судьбы меня не обойдёт (Лермонтов). – Я знал, что удар судьбы меня не обойдёт.

[источник](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r2_3_2)